# How to disable apache daemon/service - to run expressjs via nodejs

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I want to stop apache and run expressjs via nodejs

I am running:

- Linux version 2.6.32-896.16.1.lve1.4.51.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@build.cloudlinux.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Jan 17 13:19:23 EST 2018
- cPanel Version    68.0
- on fastcomet.com
- Apache Version    2.4.29

I have tried:

- chkconfig
- systemctl
- update-rc.d

but all give command not found.

----- Edit --------------

Also tried:

- service
- apache2ctl
- chkconfig

but all give command not found and `whereis` fails to find them.

Contents of /usr/sbin

```
$ ls /usr/sbin
chroot                exim              saslpasswd2  testsaslauthd
cracklib-check        pluginviewer      sendmail     tmpwatch
cracklib-format       proxyexec         snmpd        try-from
cracklib-packer       safe_finger       snmptrapd
cracklib-unpacker     saslauthd         tcpd
create-cracklib-dict  sasldblistusers2  tcpdmatch
```

Answer (score 2):

Redhat 4 is system V.

Systemctl wont work.

Use the old sysv commands.

```
service httpd stop
```

Or you should be able to stop `apache` with the `apache2ctl` command

```
apache2ctl -k stop
```

The above command is usually located in `/usr/sbin` it may need to be run from there or with the full path:

`/usr/sbin/apache2ctl`

You can then use chkconfig. Probably something like this:

`chkconfig httpd off`

You can verify it with the below command.

```
chkconfig --list | grep httpd
```

Output should look somthing like:

```
httpd           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

Comment: Thanks for this - the issue was my Shared Hosting Environment does not have root access - I posted details of the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

How to install and configure **Node.js** on **managed hosting accounts**

1) In a text editor, add the following lines to the .htaccess file in   the /home/username/public_html directory, where username represents  your account username:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:XXXXX/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:XXXXX/$1 [P,L]
```

2) In both RewriteRule lines, replace XXXXX with the port on which your
   Node.js application listens.

*Note: To run a Node.js application on a managed server, you must select an unused port, and the port number must be between 49152 and 65535 (inclusive).*

3) Save the changes to the .htaccess file, and then exit the text editor. Visitors to your web site are redirected to the Node.js application listening on the specified port.

Main issue was: Shared Hosting Environment does not have root access